# How do connect to JHipster application with Ionic?

Tags: jhipster, okta

When I try to login I get an error

I have an JHipster application up and running with oauth authentications.
I followed the instructions in the blog

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/01/30/jhipster-ionic-with-oidc-authentication

I get an error POST http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate 403 (Forbidden) when I try to login

Comment: The current version of Ionic for JHipster only works with Ionic 3.x and JHipster 5.x.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, I am aware of that after raeding many answers.  I am using JHipster v5.8.2 and Ionic v3.20